# How to remove the iFrame stubborn scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I wonder why the following iFrame has scrollbars:

```
<iframe width='600' height='200' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&key=0Aliqp0kGPjWsdERacHFDVzNzb1N3RHREZzYwVGQ5OVE&output=html&widget=true&chrome=false'></iframe>
```

Comment: browser? version?  seems to have scroll bars [only where it needs to](http://jsfiddle.net/BWwuP/show/).

Comment: or maybe you need something like http://jsfiddle.net/8ku5F/2/show/

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for the answer, but do I have to use so many scripts to remove two scrollbars? Any straightforward approach?

Comment: if all you want is to replace the entire page with the iframe you can set its size to 100% and give it a position:fixed style.  For more detailed answer, you need to provide more detail in your answer. `<iframe width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;" src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&key=0Aliqp0kGPjWsdERacHFDVzNzb1N3RHREZzYwVGQ5OVE&output=html&widget=true&chrome=false'></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

It's not iframe, It's the inner elements have a scrolls (I mean spreadsheet), because you can 
see `sheets tabs` at the bottom which is in iframe too but after that no scrollbars.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense, but how to get rid of the scrollbars?

Comment: less columns or decrease size of columns to fit in your frame

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to see the *Sheet1* and *Sheet2* tabs at the bottom you can modify the `src` of the `iframe`. If you remove `&widget=true` from the url it will stop the scrollbars from appearing. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/f2FaU/

```
<iframe width='600' height='200' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&key=0Aliqp0kGPjWsdERacHFDVzNzb1N3RHREZzYwVGQ5OVE&output=html&chrome=false"></iframe>
```

Comment: @RainLover: I am pretty sure this would have fixed your problem, so please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax wise you're using the correct parameter, `scrolling="no"`, but I recommend placing it all between double quotes.

Comment: You're probably right, but I'm not sure if it makes any difference regarding what I'm after.